# Linkedin Integration with Salesforce

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, rest-api, integration, linkedin

I'm building a job seeker platform and I want the user to extract their profile data from LinkedIn. For this purpose, I'm using the LinkedIn API to fetch the profile data from LinkedIn using Apex callout and displaying it using LWC.

I went through the LinkedIn [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/getting-access?view=li-lms-2022-08) to fetch the profile information. LinkedIn provides us with lite profile access to fetch `firstName`, `lastName` and `userProfilePicture` fields and the permission is called the `r_liteProfile`. But I need the experience, skills and education information of my job seeker as well.

I looked at numerous other posts on the same issue but they are outdated and have no answers and are not helpful as LinkedIn upgraded their version from v1 to v2.

Is there a way to fetch the full profile information using the LinkedIn API? Also, is it possible to analyse the statistics of my posts using the API data without owning a company?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: StackOverflow is the right place for your question and it looks like you're already there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73342985/full-profile-access-for-linkedin-api

Comment: Thanks! Just thought would ask here if anyone knew about this.